# Error handling casting to double with stringstream

Tags: c++, error-handling, casting, stringstream, istringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::istringstream iss;
  iss.str("1.23@45");
  double result;
  iss >> result;
  std::cout << result << std::endl;

  if (!iss.eof() || iss.fail()) {
    std::cout << "error occurred" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

*output is*

```
1.23
error occurred
```

Is there any better solution to check that all characters have been processed?

**UPDATE**

Also, I wonder if there any ways to detect *out of range* errors.

Comment: You might be interested in [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast).

Comment: @Angew, I need locale-dependent casting without setting locale globally thus I choose the solution based on streams.

Comment: You might want to use `iss >> result >> std::ws;` if it is leagal to have trailing spaces. Otherwise, I think that's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!iss.eof() || iss.fail())
```

Since the string stream hasn't reached the end of the stream yet. `eof()` is obviously false, and this `if()` condition will evaluate to true.

The results are correct: not all characters have been processed.

Comment: yes, I've covered solution with unit-test and it works. But solution looks bulky so I wonder if any better solutions exist.